# How to permanently allow macro for a trusted worksheet?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2007

I've created a worksheet which is shared amongst my colleagues with a real simply macro to show/hide rows but everytime either I or one of my colleagues opens it they get prompted to Allow marco -  is there anyway for them to permantly allow this macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change a setting in *Macro Security* within Excel so that your colleagues don't have to respond to a dialog box every time.  Be advised, though, that when you allow macro code to run automatically, this can unsuspectingly open you up to malicious code in other Excel workbooks.

The location of the settings for Macro Security is different from versions 2003 and 2007 of Excel.  In 2003 and previous, I believe the setting is visible in Tools > Macros > Macro Security.  From there, you would change the security level to low.  In Excel 2007 (and probably 2010), the setting is visible in the Developer tab on the ribbon (which you might have to make visible by toggling a checkbox in Excel Options).  From the Developer tab, click *Macro Security* and chose *Enable All Macros.*

The above is the simplest way for your colleagues to make a change to *their* system, but a better way, as others suggest, would be to digitaly sign your own work so that your colleagues don't have to open a potential security hole on their own system.

Comment: Hi Ben, as i commented below to Boofus looks like the macro is self-assigned by default and even i still get the prompt as the creator/owner -  am I missing something?

Comment: Two things: 1) While I haven't tried working with self-assigning certs on my own machine, you may still need to "install" the certificate in your root certificate store, even if it is self-signed. 2) A self-signed certificate isn't going to do you much good when it comes to your colleagues since their PCs aren't going to trust the self-signed cert that comes from your machine unless they go through the hassle of installing it. You'd need to obtain a cert through a trusted store, which could cost $100.00 and up per year.  If cost is an issue, I'd look at the the previously mentioned options.

Comment: Ok thanks Ben -  i think i'll just put a caveat in my email to my colleagues to accept that notification. I dont like the idea of them lowering their macro security settings as I know how susceptible marcros are to malicious code

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to digitally sign the project.  Microsoft's information about how to do that is here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/digitally-sign-a-macro-project-HA001231781.aspx

Comment: Thanks boofus -  looks like its self-signed by default. Assume thats not enough to get rid of the notification for me or my colleagues?

Comment: When you distribute it to your colleagues, they should have the option of accepting your certification (but I'm saying that from memory - no promises).